# Changing the queue while MPMusicPlayerController is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipod

I am using `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]` to handle playback. The app starts with a playlist and eventually while listening to a track, if the user takes a certain action I want to change the part of the playlist **AFTER** the `nowPlayingItem`.

Since I generate the original playlist and the new one, I am able to create a new queue that represents the previously played `MPMediaItems` and the new ones. Everything works fine until I try pausing, scrubbing or doing anything that affects playback. It will immediately skip to the track after the `nowPlayingItem`.

Example code:

```
- (void)exampleAction{       
    //Remove tracks after currentItem
    [self.playbackQueue removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(self.indexInQueue+1, self.playbackQueue.count-self.indexInQueue-1)];

    NSMutableArray *newQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
    //ADD ITEMS TO newQueue here

    [self.playbackQueue addObjectsFromArray:newQueue];

    MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:self.playbackQueue];
    [self.playbackController setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];    
}
```

Playback of the `nowPlayingItem` **cannot** be interrupted. Using this method, if I do not attempt to alter playback (play\pause\scrub) and the track finishes normally, everything works as it should and continues to work properly for the remainder of the playlist. It seems that modifying the playback queue during playback has some sort of side-effect that I don't understand. Can anyone give me some insight on how I can achieve what I am trying to do? This bug is killing me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling `play` on your `MPMusicPlayerController` immediately after setting the playback queue? It should produce at most a momentary blip in playback.

Comment: "Everything works fine until I try pausing, scrubbing or doing anything that affects playback." – It just skips to the next track. Also, a momentary blip is not acceptable.

Comment: Are you getting that momentary blip when you call `play` on the `MPMusicPlayerController`?

Comment: No, it just skips to the next track in the queue. Scenario: 1. Build queue. 2. Playback. 3. Change queue after nowPlayingItem. 4. Scrub to 50% of `nowPlaying Item`, or press `pause` then `play`, anything that affects playback 5. `MPMusicPlayerController` automatically skips to the next track after the `nowPlayingItem`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `MPMusicPlayerController` to me. I would file a Radar with Apple.

Comment: I actually used a tech support ticket and they confirmed that it is indeed a bug with `MPMusicPlayerController`. Looking for workarounds in the meantime...

Comment: Sounds like you might have to roll your own playback. Get the asset path from the music library and use AVFoundation to play it.